# Euro Symbol in RTF

Tags: .net, encoding, character-encoding, rtf

I'm trying to get a euro symbol to show in in a RTF document, but am not having much luck.

The RTF doc is a template, which is populated with data from .Net (by reading in the text stream and replacing tokens within it).  One of these tokens relates to a euro symbol.  My code is working as expected, in that the output RTF doc contains the euro symbol in the markup (when viewed in notepad), however, when viewed in word, etc. the euro symbol shows up as 'â‚¬'.

I assume that it's an encoding issue - can anyone help with some suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rtf should contain \'80, not the Euro symbol directly. I don't know how you're inserting the tokens, but this is what should be inserted, not the €.

For the full list, see [Complete Character List for windows-1258](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/windows-1258/list.htm). Thanks Bob.

Comment: Nice one, thanks - what character set does the 80 come from?  - I've got a load more currency symbols to do ;)

Comment: Actually, I just created a file in Word, saved it as RTF and looked at it in notepad.

Comment: The RTF specification is horribly complicated though.

Comment: Edited, add link to full list of characters provided by Bob.

Answer (score 1):

Quick google search.

Maybe one of these helps:
[Unicode Character 'EURO SIGN'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the link - eventually found it here for anyone else having fun with this...  http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/windows-1258/list.htm